# How do I use my two passports when my surname is not the same in them?

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, filipino-citizens, japanese-citizens

I have both Japanese and Philippine passports, but my surname is different on each. I have never been to Japan; I was born and raised in the Philippines.

This is my first time traveling to Japan. Which passport should I use for my flight ticket? What should I do when I get to Japan?

I don't have any idea as this will be my first time traveling abroad.

Comment: What is the reason for the different surnames? And have you tried asking the embassy for advice?

Comment: @krubo If over the age of 21, you cannot legally be a Japanese dual citizen, so the Japanese embassy will *not* be helpful.  See the answer I linked to for guidance on how to travel.

Comment: @jpatokal Different names on the passports here, which I think differentiates them from that potential duplicate.

Comment: What you have to do is fix your passports.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie That's covered in cases 2/4.